# creating a list from a nested structure in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to create a list with coefficients from a nested structure in prolog.

For example: (`structure` --> return value)

`item(koeffizient(2), exponent(2), item(koeffizient(3), exponent(3)))` --> [0,0,2,3]

`item(koeffizient(5), exponent(0), item(koeffizient(1), exponent(1), item(koeffizient(3), exponent(3))))` --> [5,1,0,3]

`item(koeffizient(5), exponent(0))` --> [5]

`item(koeffizient(5), exponent(0), item(koeffizient(2), exponent(2)))` --> [5,0,2]

How can i do this in a recursive way? Actually i have no idea how i can do this.

Thank's for any help you can give me =)

Comment: those 'return values' seem almost random...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that is not a good idea to use a recursive structure the way you have it defined, as it differentiates the last item from the others.

You can do it greedily, assuming that your structure is ordered by the exponents (as your examples show):

```
structure(Struct, Exps):-
  structure(Struct, 0, Exps).

structure(item(koeffizient(Coeff), exponent(Exp)), Exp, [Coeff]).
structure(item(koeffizient(Coeff), exponent(MExp)), Exp, [0|Tail]):-
  MExp > Exp,
  succ(Exp, NExp),
  structure(item(koeffizient(Coeff), exponent(MExp)), NExp, Tail).
structure(item(koeffizient(Coeff), exponent(Exp), StructTail), Exp, [Coeff|Tail]):-
  succ(Exp, NExp),
  structure(StructTail, NExp, Tail).
structure(item(koeffizient(Coeff), exponent(MExp), StructTail), Exp, [0|Tail]):-
  MExp > Exp,
  succ(Exp, NExp),
  structure(item(koeffizient(Coeff), exponent(MExp), StructTail), NExp, Tail).
```

Procedure `structure/2` just calls `structure/3` with exponent 0.

The first clause of `structure/3` is the base case. It returns the coefficient for the last exponent.

The second clause matches the base case when the current exponent does not match. So in this case we return a zero as the next coefficient, increments the current exponent and applies recursion.

The third clause matches the recursive case when the current exponent matches the current exponent of the structure. So it returns the corresponding coefficient, increments the current exponent and applies recursion again.

The last clause is like the second clause but applies to input structures that still have more items left (apart from the current one).

If, as your comments say the input is not ordered then it might be better to transform your input to a list of ordered tuples of the form Exp-Coeff.

With such list, your `structure/2` procedure remains the same and you can symplify `procedure/3` to this one:

```
structure([], _, []).
structure([Exp-Coeff|Tail], Exp, [Coeff|TailCoeffs]):-
  succ(Exp, NExp),
  structure(Tail, NExp, TailCoeffs).
structure([MExp-Coeff|Tail], Exp, [0|TailCoeffs]):-
  MExp > Exp,
  succ(Exp, NExp),
  structure([MExp-Coeff|Tail], NExp, TailCoeffs).
```

Comment: Thank's! The Structure is a return value from a DCG progress, made by a fellow student. Now he says, in contrast to his examples, the structure isn't ordered by the exponents. Whats the best ways to do this? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user1843596: If the structure isn't ordered by the exponents i'd suggest to apply a transformation to the structure to a more manageable structure (e.g. lists of Exp-Coeff pairs), then you can sort the list easily with `keysort/2` and build the coefficient list in a way similar to the one shown in this answer.

Comment: Ok, now i have a sorted key-value list ([Exp-Coeff, ... ]) , but i dont get it to create a list [C0,C1,...Cn] like you done it above. I would be very pleased if you can help me again.

Comment: @user1843596: I improved the answer to show how you'd do it once you have your input structure as an ordered list of Exp-Coeff tuples.

Comment: Thanks so mutch again for your help! =) Everything works now as it should.